# Redux state design for video player

Tags: javascript, redux

I want to model simple video player. It has 3 main features:

- switch to next video
- switch to prev video
- switch to the video at some index

I have next set of options available to me:

1. 3 Actions. 3 dumb action creators. All logic for validation will live in reducers.
2. 1 Action. 3 action creators with access to `getState`.
3. 1 Action. 1 Action creator. Next and prev are constructed in `select` function when mapping from `state` to component `props`.

What options should I choose and why?

I am concerned more about idiomatic approach than about make it work (all 3 will work imo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider your first option but add all logic in the action creator and into the reducer.

The reasons:
You have three distinct actions, switch to next/prev and so on, that logically fit with three distinct actions (most probably dispatched clearly by the user in the UI).

The action creator allows you to keep the reducer thin, and only responsible to update the state (so reducers can be easily composed).

By the way, in redux you are free to add your business logic in both the action creators and reducers, it really depends on your setup and organization and there is no right/wrong.

Interesting article:
http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic